# Disabling Fuzzy Searching in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am completely new to Elastic Search and I wanted to ask about some configuration. There doesn't seem to be any information about fuzzy searching in config folder. I also read about them at official documentation but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. I have elastic shield version 1.7.6 but not sure about how it works... and when I search for: "shoes - white" there are no results. But when I search for: "shoes -white" or "shoes- white" there is 1 result (in this case I am looking for exact string: "shoes - white"). Can anyone tell me where I can find some configuration with it? There should be a result when I search for the exact string (even with two spaces). My Another problem is that when I search for something like: "shoes black" it also find words like "shoes blade", "shoes blain", "shoes smack" or whatever words that corresponds to the words with 2 letters completely ignored: in this case words that ends with "ack" or starts with "bla". Where can I change it so that when I search for "shoes black" I will have the result similar to "shoes black" without this fuzzy searching. Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: There is no such configuration. It's all about which [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) is sent and what query parameters are provided. How are you searching your index? Are you using kibana by any chance?

Comment: I wonder how and where are those queries generated. No, I am not using Kibana, is it something similar to BigDesk? I tried to configure BigDesk and it couldn't connect to Elastic. Is Kibana able to help me get information about  queries that are being sent? Thx for answer.

Comment: Kibana lets you visualize and search the data. Nevermind though if you're not using it. How are you 'searching' then? If you are not using the REST api manually, you are using some tool or software to search in elasticsearch. This software or tool most likely generates your query.